# Isomorphism of fiber bundles with versus without structure group.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, fiber-bundles

Consider two fiber bundles with structure group $G$, which are isomorphic as fiber bundles without structure group (i.e., with the full group of homeomorphisms of the fiber as structure group). Are they also isomorphic as fiber bundles with structure group $G$?

In other words, the structure group constrains the transition functions of a fiber bundle, so the map from structure-group-$G$ bundles to no-structure-group bundles is not surjective. Does the structure group also constrain possible equivalences between transition functions such that the map is also not injective?

Edit: Maybe I should rather ask: Is there a natural notion of isomorphism between fiber bundles where the structure-group enters non-trivially?

Comment: I know what it means for two fiber bundles to be isomorphic, but I don't know what you mean by 'isomorphic as fiber bundles with structure group $G$'.

Comment: By "isomorphic as fiber bundles with structure group $G$" do you perhaps mean "$G$-equivariantly isomorphic"? I'm not sure that there's a standard notion of isomophism of $G$-bundles.

Comment: One thing to note is that if a fiber bundle has structure group $G$, then so does any isomorphic fiber bundle.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Thanks for your comments. So a having a structure group is really just a property and not a structure of a fibre bundle? Sorry, guess I asked this question a bit too quickly before properly looking at the definitions.

Comment: Being able to reduce the structure group to a given group is a property. My comment is that this property is preserved by isomorphism of fiber bundles.

Comment: What would now constitute an answer to your question?